# Using bash commands in expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I've tried using some bash commands in an expect script before spawning anything, and this doesn't seem to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

sudo ifdown usb0
sudo ifup usb0

expect "[sudo] password for stud:"
send "FirstPassword\r"

spawn ssh root@10.9.8.2
expect "root@10.9.8.2's password:"
send "SecondPassword\r"

expect eof
```

I've tried running this with the first part of the script commented out (because it's not neccesary to do this check 100% of the time, just better), but in that case I enter the device, and literally can't do anything there. I'd like to ifdown ifup, enter pass, ssh, enter pass, and scope to that shell.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. you can't expect to run bash commands in an expect interpreter, just like you can't run perl commands in a python interpreter -- they're different languages. If you want to run some bash commands that require user interaction (sudo), then you have to spawn bash

```
set prompt {\$ $}    ; # this is a regular expression that should match the
                       # *end* of you bash prompt. Alter it as required.
spawn bash
expect -re $prompt

send "sudo ifdown usb0\r"
expect {
    "[sudo] password for stud:" {
        send "FirstPassword\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re $prompt
}
send "sudo ifup usb0\r"
expect -re $prompt

send "ssh root@10.9.8.2\r"
expect "root@10.9.8.2's password:"
send "SecondPassword\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* the command you want to run inside an `expect` script is supposed to generate some output that you want to consume inside the script then consider running your command **outside** the script and then passing whatever value you need as a parameter.

An example for `openvpn` that requires an OTP token as a parameter:

##### autovpn.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set OTP_CODE [lindex $argv 0]

set timeout -1

spawn sudo openvpn --config my_vpn_profile.ovpn

expect "Enter Auth Username:"
send -- "myuser\r"

expect "Enter Auth Password:"
send -- "mysecret\r"

expect "CHALLENGE: Enter Authenticator Code"
send -- "$OTP_CODE\r"
expect_background
```

Now you can run the expect script passing the opt code as first argument:

```bsh
./autovpn.exp $(oathtool -b --totp 'my_otp_seed_ABCDEFGH')
```