# How to execute a single launcher as root without password?

Tags: unity, icons, root, gksudo

I want to run an executable file as root by clicking an icon. I have the following desktop file (`test.desktop`) in place:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Test Program      
Comment=Open test program
Exec=sudo taskset -c 7 /home/username/Desktop/folder1/test_program %f
Icon=/home/username/Desktop/folder1/image.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

This works, but each time I click the icon it requires me to enter my password, which is growing tiresome. I want **this one icon** to execute this one program program as root without a password prompt. I do not want to disable the password prompt for all `sudo` commands.

`test_program` above is an executable which requires root status to run correctly.

Further, if I change the `Exec=` line above to

```
Exec=gksudo -k -u root taskset -c 7 /home/username/Desktop/folder1/test_program %f
```

the program doesn't actually run, but rather opens terminal then closes terminal immediately.

How can I make this run as root without putting my password in each time?

Requested Edit #1: My edited sudoers file is given below.

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
ALL     ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/username/Desktop/folder1/test_program

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Use expect http://askubuntu.com/questions/689001/using-bash-commands-in-expect-script

Comment: «it requires me to enter my password» That means it works. Are you asking for password-less `sudo`? That would be a different question (likely duplicate of existing questions on this topic).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, your comment may help, but it isn't exactly what I want. I want this one icon to execute this one program program as root without a password prompt, not passwardless `sudo` across the board. @bodhi.zazen, thanks for the feedback. I will look for a tutorial on expect. It is definitely foreign to me.

Comment: I see. It can be done per single command, or for a selection of commands. See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/72272/271

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow execution without using sudo?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-using-sudo)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto thanks for the suggestions! This is really close to what I want, but the icon still requires the password.

Comment: Please update the question showing how you edited the `sudoers` file.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALL     ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/username/Desktop/folder1/test_program
```

This is not the command you are trying to run as `sudo`. The command is:

```
taskset -c 7 /home/username/Desktop/folder1/test_program
```

(If you click on the launcher, the `%f` will be empty and you might as well remove it)

Therefore, you need to correct the `sudoers` file, but keep in mind that you need to use absolute paths as [pointed out in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/72272/271):

```
ALL     ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/taskset -c 7 /home/username/Desktop/folder1/test_program
```

As a side note, this setting **enables every user** to run `taskset` with the given argument with `sudo`. This might or might not be what you want.

Comment: This edit actually made things worse. When I added `taskset -c 7` to the `sudoers` file as you suggested, not only does `visudo` think this new line is a typo, but clicking the icon no longer launches terminal at all.

Comment: @BFranks sorry, I overlooked the «use absolute paths to the program you are trying to use» in the answer we were talking about. Let me update my answer.

Comment: NICE WORK ANDREA!! Thank you! Works flawlessly.