# Launch VMWare Player as root from GUI in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gui, root, vmware

I want to run VMWare Player as root (because I understand this is the only way that allows me to pass a raw hard drive to my VM).

I am able to start Player from the terminal with "sudo -i vmplayer" but I can't get it to launch from the GUI. I have created a .desktop file, I have tried a shell file (allow to execute as a program), I have tried the menu editor and edited the line with which vmplayer is invoked to include sudo but nothing works. It just doesn't do anything (on the desktop).

What do I need to do to be able to just click on an icon in my favorites bar and launch vmplayer as root?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [How to run .desktop icon from sudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/1254757/618353):

1. Open your terminal and run this command

   ```
   cd /usr/share/applications
   ```

   Or

   ```
   cd /usr/local/share/applications
   ```

   where the vmware-player.desktop file exists
2. After that run this command

   ```
   sudo gedit vmware-player.desktop
   ```
3. Replace

   ```
   Exec=sudo /usr/bin/vmplayer %u
   ```
4. Save the file and run this command below

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
5. Add the following line at the end of your file

   ```
   <your-username> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vmplayer
   ```
6. Type your user name, save the file and check that your applications is there.

Hope this helps.